# What is the coefficient of $x^{2m}$ in $(1 + 4 x - 2 x^2 + 4 x^3 + x^4)^m$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

For each positive integer $m$, write $(1 + 4 x - 2 x^2 + 4 x^3 + x^4)^m = \sum_{j = 0}^{4m} b_j^{(m)} x^j$.
What is $b_{2m}^{(m)}$ in terms of $m$?

Comment: hint:$x^{2m} = (x^2)^m$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$I=(1 + 4 x - 2 x^2 + 4 x^3 + x^4)^m=((x+1)^4-8x^2)^m=\sum_{i=0}^{m}(-8)^i(x+1)^{4m-4i}x^{2i}$$
$$I=\sum_{i=0}^{m}\sum_{j=0}^{4m-4i}(-8)^i x^{4m-2i-j}$$

Comment: How about the binomial coefficients? E.g. $((x + 1)^4 - 8 x^2)^m = \sum_{i=0}^m \binom{m}{i} (-8)^i (x + 1)^{4m - 4i} x^{2i}$.

Comment: @ColinTan Repeated binomial expansion.

Answer (score 0):

We may factor as follows:

$$x^4+4x^3-2x^2+4x+1=(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)(x+d)$$

$$a=1+\sqrt2+r$$

$$b=1+\sqrt2-r$$

$$c=1-\sqrt2+ir'$$

$$d=1-\sqrt2-ir'$$

where $r=\sqrt{2+\sqrt8}$ and $r'=\sqrt{-2+\sqrt8}$

By Vieta's formulas,

$$b^{(m)}_{2m}=\sum_{1\le i_1<i_2<\dots<i_{2m}\le4m}x_{i_1}x_{i_2}x_{i_3}\dots x_{i_{2m}}$$

where $x_{i_{4n+1}}=a$, $x_{i_{4n+2}}=b$, $x_{i_{4n+3}}=c$, $x_{i_{4n+4}}=d$ and $n=0,1,2,\dots$

Comment: Is there a way to write $b_{2m}^{(m)}$ in closed form, i.e. without a summation sign?

Comment: @ColinTan We still thinking about this, give us some time XD